# Spring boot call async while others in progress

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, asynchronous

I have a requirement where I am validating a data hitting a rest call like

```
@Async
private void validate() throws WebClientResponseException {
    this.webClient.method(HttpMethod.GET)
            .uri(urlBuilder -> urlBuilder.path(uripath).build())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Response.class).block();

   // throws exception in case of validation failure
}
```

I am calling this function from another function

```
RETURN_TYPE func() {
    validate();
    //rest of the code and validations

    service.save(input);
}
```

My requirement is `validate()` should be called asynchronously and rest of the code and validations should be called parallelly.

It should not execute service.save() until both of them finishes. Is it possible to do that?